# Carousel slide show in not responsive to smaller device

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="background1.jpg" style="height: 700px;" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="wallpaper.png" style="height: 700px;" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="background3.jpg" style="height: 700px;" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here I have used all images of different heights and give them fixed height to be looked good on big screen but how do I make them responsive to smaller device because on smaller screen slide show looks too much distorted. I could use media queries but is there any other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Set w-100 on parent DIV:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel w-100 slide" data-ride="carousel" >
```

Comment: Carosel slide width working fine but it has problem with height. Due to fixed height of images, on smaller device it looks way big height wise.

Comment: you have to add img-fluid to the image class  <img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="background3.jpg"

Comment: I did try try to add a img-fluid class but because of fixed height hard coded, on smaller width images are not responsive and so they look all stretched out of the screen. One more thing, this is happening because all the images are of different heights and if I take out the fixed height stated, slide show is responsive but looks like bouncing images because of mismatched height. I tried to set the same height property for all of 'em but aspect ratio does not let me do it and I am stuck. I really want to use all these images. Plus I styled the heights of images in percentage but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it other way around. I downloaded the same size and width pics then give them heights and width in terms of vw and vh.